# MPMoviePlayerController not playing the video

Tags: iphone, ios5, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play videos in iphone app and i am using MPMoviePlayerController. It used to work fine but suddenly when i tried to integrate the viewcontroller class which plays the video, it stopped playing. I tried to import the MediaPlayer Framework and did a lot of R&D stuff but still its not working. I am using this code..

```
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL URLWithString:xmlParser.videoUrlLink];
self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayerController];
//[moviePlayerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
[self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(5,65,307,200)];    
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayerController.view];
[self.moviePlayerController play];
```

I am getting a warning and the method moviePlayBackDidFinish: is getting called repeatedly even before the video is played. The warning is

```
An instance 0x168da0 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers 
were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become 
mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop 
here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info: ( Context: 0x0, Property: 
0x10b570> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x117ab0>
```

Can someone please help me on how to get out of this....It would be of great help....

Comment: Don't you have a leak at `self.moviePlayerController` ?

Comment: @A-Live: Even if i change that object to just moviePlayerController i am still not able to play the video....

Comment: @A-Live: When i was searching for a solution in StackOverflow i found that we need to try it that way to get the pblm solved.. pls check the same.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035481/ios-5-an-instance-of-avplayeritem-was-deallocated

Comment: Setting it via ivar, you will still get a leak as the old value is not released, try to get rid of the memory issue first if it is there.

Comment: He might also have a memory issue, the code he listed is not complete.

Comment: @A-Live: I have tried to create a new instance but still the video is not playing...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11754/discussion-between-a-live-and-pradeep-reddy-kypa)