# MPMoviePlayerController not playing URL from GDataFeedYouTubeVideo

Tags: xcode, mpmovieplayer

I am using GDataFeedYouTubeVideo to populate a tableview with images and titles. This works. I want to play the video after the cell is selected. I am using the url from the feed to pass to the MPMoviePlayer and it looks like it loads because the screen goes black, the moviePlaybackDidFinish is called but does not play the video and goes back to displaying the tableview? An example url from the feed is:

https://www.youtube.com/v/o7QAMH3qRvU?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata

This does work from a browser but not in the MPMoviePlayer? Please help me figure this one out. I would rather not have to write some hack routine to replace or remove the URLString returned by the feed. I am using ARC & Storyboards. The second time I select a cell I get:

An instance 0xce6a7b0 of class AVPlayerItem was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it...

Yes I did try what was suggested in:
[iOS 5 an instance of AVPlayerItem was deallocated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035481/ios-5-an-instance-of-avplayeritem-was-deallocated)
and this did not fix it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    YouTubeVideo *item = [searchList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (item != nil) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:item.URLString];
        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:moviePlayer];
        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)moviePlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:player];

    if ([player respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried this and it works if I format the url slightly:
https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser